# $GLOBALS and $_COOKIE not preserved through page changes in Safari

Tags: php, cookies, safari

I have various variables saved into $GLOBALS and $_COOKIE in my PHP. When using Safari, these values aren't retained (I am logged out, etc.). It is not a code problem though, apparently, because in Firefox, these values *are* preserved through all page changes just fine.

Any ideas on what about Safari could be causing this?

Some code (upon successful login):

```
        setcookie("username", $loginName, time() + 3600);
        setcookie("userID", $user['id'], time() + 3600);
        // Since setcookie() only kicks in when the reply happens (i.e., when user goes to NEXT page,
        // or refreshes this page), needed to do this:
        $_COOKIE['userID'] = $user['id'];

        $GLOBALS['userID'] = $user['id'];
```

This works, both in FF and Safari. The issue is when a new page is loaded. In FF all is fine, but in Safari the values are lost.

On a newly loaded page, I have, for testing purposes:

```
echo "G: ".$GLOBALS['userID']."<br>C:".$_COOKIE["userID"]."//"
```

Again, in FF this works (and I remain logged in, etc.), but not in Safari.

Comment: Wild guess, do you have cookies enabled in safari?

Comment: You will loose all globals in any browser when the script ends (before it reaches the browser...). Do you mean `$_SESSION` and `$_COOKIES` perhaps?

Comment: @EWit-Yes, plus I fiddled with the code and on the page where the user actually logs in, the browser successfully prints both the $GLOBALS and $_COOKIE values

Comment: @jeroen-I'm not sure what exactly you mean…I have been using $GLOBALS and $_COOKIE and it has been working in FF…? You are saying that they usually do not work?

Comment: You should post your code, it's not very clear what you are asking. Cookies for example are not avaible in the script where you set them, you need to reload or go to another page to be able to see them.

Comment: @jeroen-Added code…anything more needed?

Comment: isn't it that Safari blocks all cookie by default?